# make div with image and text responsive css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have placed an image and text over the div with background as below

[image]

The CSS done for this is as below

```
#image_container {
background: url('images/1.jpg') no-repeat;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
margin: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main_image {
height: 220px;
margin:-5px;
}
.text {
padding: 5px; 
}
.ltext {
margin-top: -5px;
}
```

and HTML markup is as below

```
<a href="blog/<link to post>" style="color:inherit">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div id="image_container" class="">
<img src="images/blog/1.jpg" 
class="main_image" alt=""/>
<div class="text">
<img src="images/dot.png" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 
col-lg-12" alt="divider" style="max-width:100%"/>
Mouting Memories
<p class="ltext">
<?php echo date('l', $time).', '.date('F', $time).' ' ?><?php echo    
date('d', $time).', '.date('Y', $time);?>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

But with above approach the inside image and text is  not getting displayed properly on screen size chnage.It is getting displayed as [here](http://cl.ly/image/093e452J1W23?_ga=1.256451019.1567375848.1423935200)

Please help.

Comment: Could you share the images you used in your css and in your HTML? So I can run the entire code properly on my computer

Comment: @shoriwa-shaun-benjamin here are links http://cl.ly/image/452P340O0K1z?_ga=1.248719559.1567375848.1423935200 , http://cl.ly/image/0N1p1l0n311s?_ga=1.248719559.1567375848.1423935200 , http://cl.ly/image/3k0X2v0m1L1s?_ga=1.248719559.1567375848.1423935200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#image_container {
background: url('blogpost_bg.jpg') no-repeat;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
margin: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.main_image {
height: 220px;
margin:-5px;
}
.text {
padding: 5px; 
}
.ltext {
margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Add `background-size:100% 100%;` to your CSS for the `#image_container`

Your HTML and PHP

```
<a href="blog/<link to post>" style="color:inherit">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div id="image_container" class="">
<img src="images/blog/1.jpg" 
class="main_image" alt=""/>
<div class="text">
<img src="images/dot.png" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 
col-lg-12" alt="divider" style="max-width:100%"/><br>
Mouting Memories
<p class="ltext">
<?php echo date('l', $time).', '.date('F', $time).' ' ?><?php echo    
date('d', $time).', '.date('Y', $time);?>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Add a `<br>` after the image (`<img>`) so the test is forced to the next line even if it has enough space to fit on the same line as the image

Also your PHP isnt very good.

It should rather be

```
<?php echo date('l, F d, Y', $time);?>
```

That's the quick way to do it. The better way to do it is to use CSS for the background instead of that image you have used because that image stretches and pixelates. See below for better CSS using -webkit-box-shadow,-moz-box-shadow and box-shadow instead of a background image.

```
#image_container {
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 17px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 17px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 17px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 30px;
margin: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Looks cleaner with that CSS